# How to pass a template template non-type member function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I would like to pass (to a template member function) a pointer to a another template member function as a template template non-type parameter.

Here is what I've tried:

```
enum Unit { model_unit, nanometers, meters };

struct Material {
     double rho;
};

struct Point {
    double x, y, z;
};

struct Impl{

    template<Unit unit>
    Material * LookupMat_1(const Point& p) {
        return nullptr; // let's suppose it returns a valid pointer
    }

    template<Unit unit>
    Material * LookupMat_2(const Point& p) {
        return nullptr; // let's suppose it returns a valid pointer
    }

    // compiler error here:
    // expected 'class' or 'typename' before 'Material'
    // template<template<Unit> Material * (Impl::*LookupFunc)(const Point&)
    //                         ^~~~~~~~
    template<template<Unit> Material * (Impl::*LookupFunc)(const Point&) >
    Material * GetMaterial(const Point & p) {

        return (this->*LookupFunc<Unit::model_unit>)(p);
    }

    void DoSomething() {

        Point p = {};

        auto mat_1 = GetMaterial<LookupMat_1>(p);
        auto mat_2 = GetMaterial<LookupMat_2>(p);
    }
};

int main() {

    Impl i;

    i.DoSomething();

}
```

My syntax is wrong, the compiler says:

> ```
> main.cpp:25:29: error: expected 'class' or 'typename' before 'Material'
> template<template<Unit> Material * (Impl::*LookupFunc)(const Point&)
>                         ^~~~~~~~
> ```

I cannot figure out the right syntax.

`LookupFunc` is a template of type `Material * (Impl::*)(const Point&)` which is a pointer to a member fonction.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

What am I missing?

Comment: A template template parameter is always a class template, not a function template. The syntax is always `template <...> class-or-typename`.

Comment: @n.m. So should I be able to do this using a template class as a functor?

Comment: There are no pointers to templates. You can use pointers to specific instantiations of  templates however.

Comment: Maybe this can move You forward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213761/what-are-some-uses-of-template-template-parameters-in-c#213811

Comment: And also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115048/template-member-function-pointers#10115067

Comment: @PaulR Yeah, but I would like to have the template instantiated by the GetMaterial instantiation, so I don't need to give the unit at the GetMaterial call site.

Comment: *using a template class as a functor* Yes I believe this should be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the class-template-as-functor way of doing this.

```
template<Unit unit>
struct LookupMat_1
{
   Material * operator()(const Point& p) {
       return nullptr;
   }
};

template<Unit unit>
struct LookupMat_2
{
   Material * operator()(const Point& p) {
       return nullptr;
   }
};

template<template<Unit> typename LookupMat>
Material * GetMaterial(const Point & p)
{
    return LookupMat<Unit::model_unit>()(p);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I ended up doing, after reading your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As explained in comments, there isn't a single pointer to a template function (or method) because isn't a function but a set of functions.

The best I can imagine to do something similar (I mean... explicating the `Unit` type inside `GetMaterial()`) is to add a couple of sub-structs in `Impl` with static template methods

```
   struct lm1
    {
      template <Unit U>
      static Material * func (Point const & p)
       { return nullptr; }
    };

   struct lm2
    {
      template <Unit U>
      static Material * func (Point const & p)
       { return nullptr; }
    };
```

then rewrite `GetMaterial()` as follows

```
template <typename T>
Material * GetMaterial (Point const & p)
 { return T::template func<Unit::model_unit>(p); }
```

and use it this way

```
void DoSomething()
 {
   Point p = {};

   auto mat_1 = GetMaterial<lm1>(p);
   auto mat_2 = GetMaterial<lm2>(p);
 }
```

This way you pass to `GetMaterial()` a single type (`lm1` or `lm2`) that contains the full set of template functions; then, inside `GetMaterial()`, you select the right function explicating `Unit::model_unit`.

The following is a full working example

```
enum Unit { model_unit, nanometers, meters };

struct Material
 { double rho; };

struct Point
 { double x, y, z; };

struct Impl
 {
   struct lm1
    {
      template <Unit U>
      static Material * func (Point const & p)
       { return nullptr; }
    };

   struct lm2
    {
      template <Unit U>
      static Material * func (Point const & p)
       { return nullptr; }
    };


   template <typename T>
   Material * GetMaterial (Point const & p)
    { return T::template func<Unit::model_unit>(p); }

   void DoSomething()
    {
      Point p = {};

      auto mat_1 = GetMaterial<lm1>(p);
      auto mat_2 = GetMaterial<lm2>(p);
    }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Impl i;

   i.DoSomething();
 }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Why is `template` required in `return T::template func<Unit::model_unit>(p);` ? I've never seen this.

Comment: @ThreeStarProgrammer57 - sometimes that  `template` is required to tell the compiler that the called method is a `template` one; frankly I have great troubles to understand when, exactly, is required and when isn't required. This case seems to be required.